# Unsaved TeX file lost after TeXStudio crash

Tags: errors, texstudio, mac

I was compiling a TeX file and I forgot to save it, I executed several times before TeXStudio crashes and I could not find my document anymore, both `.tex` or PDF version. Any chances I can recover my file :(

Comment: Make a backup on a usb drive and put that in a drawer of your desk, better save then sorry.

Comment: Every time you hit *Compile!* the tex-document will/has to be saved to inform LaTeX about the newest changes. So, unless TeXstudio now erases files, it has to be somewhere around. What is your os? Does it hide file endings?

Comment: Thank you Johannes_B, I would like to recover the pdf file but couldn't find any, Im using Mac OS X and it does show the files name extensions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about TeX, but rather about recovering lost files.